# Initializing a GameObject[] array in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to C# and Unity and have been trying to get this script to work to no avail. the only compiler error is a NullReference Error with my GameObject[] links array when it's first being used at `links[0].transform.Translate(P);` is there some sort of initialization I'm missing?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GrapplingGunTest : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 grapplePoint;
    private LineRenderer lr;
    public LayerMask whatIsGrappleable;
    public Transform lineOrigin, Trajectory, Player;
    public GameObject[] links = new GameObject[10];
    public Rigidbody[] body = new Rigidbody[10];
    public SpringJoint[] joint = new SpringJoint[10];
    
    private float maxDistance = 100f;


    void Awake() {
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Update() {
         StartGrapple();
  
    }

    //Called after Update
    void LateUpdate() {
        DrawRope();

    if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryHandTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.LTouch)==true) {
            Pull();
        }
    }
    public Vector3 LerpByDistance(Vector3 A, Vector3 B, float x)
{
    Vector3 P = x * Vector3.Normalize(B - A) + A;
    return P;
}
    /// <summary>
    /// Call whenever we want to start a grapple
    /// </summary>
    void StartGrapple() {

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Trajectory.position, Trajectory.forward, out hit, maxDistance, whatIsGrappleable)) {
            grapplePoint = hit.point;
            
            float val = 0.1f;
            Vector3 P = LerpByDistance(Player.position, hit.point, val);
            Vector3 Pp;
            body[0] = links[0].gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            links[0].transform.Translate(P);
            joint[0] = Player.gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            joint[0].autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            joint[0].connectedBody = body[0];
            joint[0].spring = 8f;
            joint[0].damper = 10f;
            joint[0].massScale = 4.5f;
            joint[0].maxDistance = (Vector3.Distance(P, Player.position) * 0.8f);
            joint[0].minDistance = Vector3.Distance(P, Player.position) * 0.1f;
            
            for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
            val = val+0.1f;
            Pp = P;
            P = LerpByDistance(Player.position, hit.point, val);
            
            body[i] = links[i].gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            links[i].transform.Translate(P);
            joint[i] = links[i-1].gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            joint[i].autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            joint[i].connectedBody = body[i];
            joint[i].spring = 8f;
            joint[i].damper = 10f;
            joint[i].massScale = 4.5f;
            joint[i].maxDistance = (Vector3.Distance(P, Player.position) * 0.8f);
            joint[i].minDistance = (Vector3.Distance(P, Player.position) * 0.1f);
        
            }
            
            joint[10] = links[9].gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            joint[10].autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            joint[10].connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;
            joint[9].spring = 8f;
            joint[9].damper = 10f;
            joint[9].massScale = 4.5f;
            joint[9].maxDistance = (Vector3.Distance(P, Player.position) * 0.8f);
            joint[9].minDistance = Vector3.Distance(P, Player.position) * 0.1f;

            lr.positionCount = 12;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Call whenever we want to stop a grapple
    /// </summary>
    void StopGrapple() {

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        Destroy(joint[i]);
        Destroy(links[i]);
        }
        lr.positionCount = 0;
    }

    private Vector3 currentGrapplePosition;
    
    void DrawRope() {
        //If not grappling, don't draw rope
        if (!joint[0]) return;

        
        lr.SetPosition(0, lineOrigin.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, links[0].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(2, links[1].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(3, links[2].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(4, links[3].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(5, links[4].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(6, links[5].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(7, links[6].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(8, links[7].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(9, links[8].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(10, links[9].transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(11, grapplePoint);
        
    }

    void Pull() {
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        joint[i].maxDistance = joint[i].maxDistance - 0.1f;
        }
        
    }


    public bool IsGrappling() {
        return joint[0] != null;
    }

    public Vector3 GetGrapplePoint() {
        return grapplePoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: you never assign anything to links[0], links[1], etc so they are all `null`. If these are supposed to be empty gameobjects, then you probably want to use a [GameObject constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html)

Comment: Or you didnt put them in the inspector